# Need help to target element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I need some help to select an element in jquery...

With the following code

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" id="target">link</a>
                </div>
                <span>Hello</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I need to target the *`<span>`* tag but I only know the id of *`<a>`* tag.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: So... from the `a` element, it's one up to the parent and then the next sibling? Check out jQuery's traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#target').parent().next('span');
```

Comment: `.closest` does not work here... it looks for an ancestor matching the selector. I'm shocked it got upvoted before the edit.

Comment: .next is working done. (I have already tried .closet without success). thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You can go up to the parent and then get the next element which will be the `<span>`:

```
$("#target").parent().next()
```

Comment: Should work.  Breaks if there are any elements between span and it's sibling div though.

Comment: Yeah, but yours assumes there's only one sibling span and Jamiec's also assumes the span is the very next item.  If you don't tag the item with a class or something like that, then you have to rely on position.

Comment: Yeah, I mean all these solutions rely on a set DOM structure to some degree, I was just trying to prevent the question asker from being confused if (s)he runs into issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if closest() will work because it only searches up the DOM tree, through ancestors.  Try

```
$('#target').parent().siblings('span');
```

If you're not sure just how far back up the DOM tree the span is, you can test the siblings of each parent of #target.  I could be wrong on all this though lol

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    a=jQuery("#target").parents('li').find('span').html();
    alert(a);
    });
    </script>
```

you can target span by this code